# How does this boolean expression evaluate?

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

[From Three.js:](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/CubeGeometry.js)

```
this.sides.px && buildPlane( 'z', 'y',   1 * flip, - 1, depth, height, - width_half, this.materials[ 0 ] ); // px
this.sides.nx && buildPlane( 'z', 'y', - 1 * flip, - 1, depth, height, width_half, this.materials[ 1 ] );   // nx
this.sides.py && buildPlane( 'x', 'z',   1 * flip,   1, width, depth, height_half, this.materials[ 2 ] );   // py
this.sides.ny && buildPlane( 'x', 'z',   1 * flip, - 1, width, depth, - height_half, this.materials[ 3 ] ); // ny
this.sides.pz && buildPlane( 'x', 'y',   1 * flip, - 1, width, height, depth_half, this.materials[ 4 ] );   // pz
this.sides.nz && buildPlane( 'x', 'y', - 1 * flip, - 1, width, height, - depth_half, this.materials[ 5 ] ); // nz
```

What does this boolean expression return? If it returns a boolean value, where does it go?
(I see no assignment!) How does it evaluate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that there is no assignment. These statements utilize the optimization used by the `&&` operator. The `&&` operator evaluates to true if both the right hand and left hand sides evaluate to true. Thus, if the left hand side is false, it does not even have to check the right hand side, as the result will be false anyway, and it is not evaluated at all.

Thus, this code:

```
this.sides.px && buildPlane( 'z', 'y',   1 * flip, - 1, depth, height, - width_half, this.materials[ 0 ] ); // px
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
if (this.sides.px) {
    buildPlane( 'z', 'y',   1 * flip, - 1, depth, height, - width_half, this.materials[ 0 ] );
}
```

Comment: If both sides are "truthy", technically  the `&&` will evaluate to the value of the right operand, not necessarily to `true`, but the outcome here is the same of course since the result is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

It only evals the second part of the expression if the first part is true. && is a short-circuit operator in JS :) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation for more details.

Each of these statements are evaluated separately, but each could be replaced by `if (this.sides.??) buildPlane(..);` for code clarity.

Comment: Actually, no, buildPlane does NOT have to return a boolean to make this work in JavaScript.  JavaScript is weakly typed.

Comment: does  buildPlane function return a boolean?? i didnt see return keyword in its definition..

Answer (score 1):

Actually this code snippet is 6 statements, not a single expression.  Each statement is an expression evaluation.

Each statement is a boolean expression involving the `&&` operator.  To evaluate these expressions, JavaScript first evaluates the left part, then ONLY if the left part is true, evaluates the second part.  The second part is a function call that has a side effect, nothing is "returned."

The use of `&&` in this fashion is common.  It is a way to say "only make this function call if a condition is true."

Answer (score 1):

Code like that takes advantage of **short circuiting**, the fact that logical and (`&&`) and logical or (`||`) only execute the side of the expressions if they are relevant.

Say I have `a && b`. If `a` is false, `a && b` is always false no matter what `b` is so doesn't need to be checked. Similarly, if I have `a || b`, if `a` is true, then `a || b` is always true no matter what `b` is so doesn't need to be checked.

Therefore Javascript only checks `a`. If `a` happens to be true, then it checks `b`. If `a` happens to be in a form like that (probably a number from what I can tell), then they are checking if the number `!= 0`. If yes, then it executes the second code block. The return value of this operation is discarded since it isn't assigned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
this.sides.px && buildPlane( 'z', 'y',   1 * flip, - 1, depth, height, - width_half, this.materials[ 0 ] );
```

will yield same result as this:

```
if (this.sides.px) {
   buildPlane( 'z', 'y',   1 * flip, - 1, depth, height, - width_half, this.materials[ 0 ] );
}
```

It saves a couple of lines of code, but may not be as clear to everyone versus using an `if` statement.